# Get full path name of file and its size using awk

Tags: bash, list, awk, spaces

I want to get the `file names followed by their size` for all files having size in MB or GB. I have done this much so far :

```
LIST=$(ls -lh -d -1 $PWD/{*,} | awk '{ print $9":"$5 }')
for i in $LIST
do
    if [[ $( echo "$i" | cut -f2 -d: | egrep "M|G" | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
                                     # egrep not working, only finds M
    then
            echo "$i" >> bigfiles
    fi
done
```

What I am getting is :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ test/findbig
/home/amit/Batch:3.8M
/home/amit/Black:3.6M
```

What I want is :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ test/findbig
/home/amit/Batch File Programming.pdf:3.8M
/home/amit/Black Panther - Legend Has It ( Instrumental ).opus:3.6M
```

Basically, everything is working fine except `filenames` that I get are not complete. Only first word is shown. I can't figure out whether there is something wrong with logic or syntax but I think it has something to do with `awk`.

So, How do I get the full path names of files (having spaces in between) in the output ?

I have tried the [loop trick in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179100/7975442), but don't know how to get both of the columns to fit in.

Comment: Its because the whitespace n the filename is also a delimiter in the list.

Comment: You could just simplify the script to do just `du -BM $PWD | awk ' $1 ~ /M|G/ && $1 != "0M" {print $2":"$1}'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the spaces in your file names. The for loop uses spaces as delimeter. Therefore the first item in your list will be "/home/amit/Batch", second item "File" and so on.

You can use while loop instead of for, something like :

```
ls -lh -d -1 $PWD/{*,} | awk '{ print $9":"$5 }' | while read LINE
do
    echo ${LINE}
    # do your stuff here
done
```

As an aside, if your only intention is to find out large files, you may want to check out disk usage command :

```
$ du -a | sort -rn | head
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` and the convenient occurrence of the filename at the right-side of the `ls -l` listing.  `read` puts all the "extra" fields into the final variable:

```
function f_getfields
{
   local perm lnk uname grp size d1 d2 d3 filename
   while read perm lnk uname grp size d1 d2 d3 filename
   do
      echo "$filename $size"
   done <  <(ls -l)
}

f_getfields
```

Comment: Parsing `ls`? The idea is great, but would be good to recommend other tools than `ls`, may be `du` or `stat`

Comment: `stat` is not POSIX, its generally available on Linux, but not other UNIXs.  `du` maybe.  I agree that parsing `ls` is a bad thing in general, but until `bash` has a built-in `stat` (like most languages) then parsing *some* external program output will be needed if the file size is required.